# Gcc-multilib for Fedora

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora, sasm

I'm trying to install gcc-multilib on fedora, but I cannot find out how. AFAIK it is a Debian/Ubuntu specific package. Nevertheless, it is required for SASM IDE, in order to compile and debug FASM, NASM and gas assembly.

Comment: Why do you believe it is required exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closes equivalent on Fedora are the 32-bit development libraries, `glibc-devel.i686`, `libstdc++-devel.i686`, and so on, and perhaps also their `-static.i686` counterpart.